# Rails Slim confirmation dialog before server submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, slim-lang

I've got this Rails Slim code which I am trying to use to create a confirmation dialog before submitting to the server, but I'm not sure how to do a modal popup for this.

Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a6451b6714981667d2d4e349e3d7d32

Basically, I want to trigger the modal popup for either of these two buttons and submit using this approve/reject route. Thanks.

```
= link_to 'Management Approve', approve_visitor_management_visitors_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-block", data: { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
= link_to 'Management Reject', reject_visitor_management_visitors_path, class: "btn btn-danger btn-block", data: { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, modals aren't something that come out-of-the-box with rails.

Modals are just a stylized way of showing and hiding blocks of html without issuing another server request (reloading the page).  To change html content without reloading the page, you'll need to use javascript.

Front end frameworks like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/), and [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), do include out-of-the-box modal implementations which bundle up the html, css, and javascript required.  If your project isn't already using one of these, I'd suggest working through a tutorial on implementing one of them.  Bootstrap is very common.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have bootstrap included as css framework to your project thus you need modal layout, here is the one i have in my working project, it is erb, but not a big deal to switch it to slim. As David mentioned you better look at either bootstrap or so. I actually can see that there are few standard class names in your code meaning you may have already css framework included (bootstrap). So here we go with my working example:

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a id="eventUrl" class="btn btn-success" target="_blank">More details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To switch this to slim use

.classname for entire div class=blabla.

Secondly you need to bind your button to have modal shown up and here is how you want to do this

Your js is simple

```
$("Button").click ->
  $('#fullCalModal').modal()
```

If you need help let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `confirm` from the `data` hash. That should be passed directly to `link_to`. This will give you the standard browser-implemented alert box (i.e. modal popup).

```
= link_to 'Management Approve', approve_visitor_management_visitors_path, method: :post, class:"btn btn-success btn-block", confirm: 'Are you sure?'

= link_to 'Management Reject', reject_visitor_management_visitors_path, method: :post, class:"btn btn-danger btn-block", confirm: 'Are you sure?'
```

Notice I've also added `method` to the arguments. I'm assuming these are both POST requests. If not, just change them to whatever is accurate.